# How can I search for a dot an a number in sed or awk and prefix the number with a leading zero?

Tags: awk, sed, freebsd

I am trying to modify the name of a large number of files, all of them with the following structure:

```
4.A.1 Introduction to foo.txt
2.C.3 Lectures on bar.pdf
3.D.6 Processes on baz.mp4
5.A.8 History of foo.txt
```

And I want to add a leading zero to the last digit:

```
4.A.01 Introduction to foo.txt
2.C.03 Lectures on bar.pdf
3.D.06 Processes on baz.mp4
5.A.08 History of foo.txt
```

At first I am trying to get the new names with `sed` (FreeBSD implementation):

```
ls | sed 's/\.[0-9]/0&/'
```

But I get the zero before the `.`

Note: replacing the second dot would also work. I am also open to use `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pipeline should work for you:

```
ls | sed 's/\.\([0-9]\)/.0\1/'
```

The `sed` command here will capture the digit and replace it with a preceding `0`.

Here, `\1` references the first (and in this case only) capture group - the parenthesized expression.

Answer (score 3):

While it may have worked for you here, in general [slicing and dicing `ls` output is fragile](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), whether using `sed` or `awk` or anything else. Fortunately one can accomplish this robustly in plain old POSIX `sh` using globbing and [fancy-pants parameter expansions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073):

```sh
for f in [[:digit:]].[[:alpha:]].[[:digit:]]\ ?*; do
    # $f = "[[:digit:]].[[:alpha:]].[[:digit:]] ?*" if no files match.
    if [ "$f" != '[[:digit:]].[[:alpha:]].[[:digit:]] ?*' ]; then
        tail=${f#*.*.}              # filename sans "1.A." prefix
        head=${f%"$tail"}           # the "1.A." prefix
        mv "$f" "${head}0${tail}"
    fi
done
```

*(EDIT: Filter out filenames that don't match desired format.)*

Comment: This is more concise, I finally did the way I shared in my contributed answer (for me it is safer and easier to read, probably lack of experience with `sh`).

Comment: BTW if there are other files in the directory which do not follow the pattern the solution prefixes them with zero. But it is still very valid information to know that `sh` can do this.

Comment: @M.E. Good point; I have edited the solution to filter out undesired filenames.

Answer (score 1):

*I am also open to use awk.*

Let `file.txt` content be:

```
4.A.1 Introduction to foo.txt
2.C.3 Lectures on bar.pdf
3.D.6 Processes on baz.mp4
5.A.8 History of foo.txt
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$3="0" $3;print}' file.txt
```

outputs

```
4.A.01 Introduction to foo.txt
2.C.03 Lectures on bar.pdf
3.D.06 Processes on baz.mp4
5.A.08 History of foo.txt
```

Explanation: I set dot (`.`) as both field seperator and output field seperator, then for every line I add leading 0 to third column (`$3`) by concatenating 0 and said column. Finally I `print` such altered line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\S*\./&0/' file
```

This appends `0` after the last `.` in the first string of non-empty characters in each line.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps somebody else, as an alternative to @costaparas answer:

```
ls | sed -E -e 's/^([0-9][.][A-Z][.])/\10/' > files
```

To then create the script the files:

```
cat files | awk '{printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", $0, $0}' | sed 's/\.0/\./' > movefiles.sh
```